# MYSQL: select entries with non-intersecting spatial objects

Tags: mysql, sql, spatial

I'm using MySQL to determine select regions from 2 tables, some which overlap and some which don't. I can successfully select overlapping regions using:

```
SELECT chrom, site
FROM
    table1 AS s 
    STRAIGHT_JOIN
    table2 AS i 
    ON MBRINTERSECTS(PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',s.chrom,' ',s.site,')')), i.Line_string) 
    ORDER BY RAND() limit 5;
```

Table1 has two columns of integer values which I converted into points that I intersected with a linestring in table2 to give entries (in this example just the chrom and site columns) that fall on any line in table2. However, I additionally want entries from table1 that do not intersect ANY linestrings in table2.

I tried to do this using MBRDISJOINT, but perhaps I don't fully understand how it works because I get some results that actually intersect entries in table2 (this may have to do with my use of STRAIGHT_JOIN, but I don't know how else to do this).

Comment: I might be way off with this...but a straight_join is pretty much an inner join.  What I've done for spatial queries in the past is a cross join...and then the on clause you have here becomes a where clause (cross join means it evaluates all combinations between s and i).   apologies in advance if this isn't close as I'm only used to spatial in postgres

Comment: Some assumptions here, like Twelfth I don't use MySQL.  Firstly, have you tried ON NOT rather than ON?  Not sure if you can do this, but worth a suggestion.  Secondly, MBR isn't the right function to use as results could intersect the bounding rectangle created by MBR... but that doesn't mean they intersect the actual geography.  Change MBRINTERSECTS To ST_INTERSECTS (again that's from memory, look it up).  Hope either helps.